# Any reason I couldn't replace my entire fuse box with self-resetting breakers?

Tags: electrical, fuse, fuse-panel

I'm always rewiring something or upgrading a component here or there on my vehicle. I recently discovered self-resetting breakers that can replace standard automotive fuses.

This seems like a silver bullet to never having to buy fuses again, but I'm concerned there may be some tradeoffs I'm not aware of. Are there? Could heat be an issue if the entire fuse panel was filled with these?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A fuse blowing indicates something is wrong. This could of course be a transient that just requires a fuse replacement or a trip reset, but what if it's something more serious, like a short allowing high current to flow through sensitive components, or to ignite something flammable? Or an indication of failure of an expensive part.

A self resetting trip removes the human from the chain, so how will you know what is wrong, or potentially even that something is wrong.

Please don't do it - it's a massive safety issue.

Comment: A fuse is to protect something that is significantly more expensive than a replacement fuse.  If it blows it means it did its job and you should figure out what went wrong.

This isn't as bad as putting in a copper wire override, but you'll cause electronics to repeatedly suffer bursts of over-voltage/amperage, which can damage them.

Comment: What about using non self-resettable ones ? They would still indicate something is wrong and you need to manually reset them, but at the same time won't need replacement like conventional fuses. Looks like the best of both worlds, right ?